# "Username or Password is not correct" - getting the same message

Tags: c#, ms-access

I tried to make a login page. But, it always show this message:

> Username or Password is not correct

While I am pretty sure that my username and password are correct.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox_user.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox_password.Text))
    //txt_name.Text == String.IsNullOrEmpty || txt_family.Text == String.IsNullOrEmpty || txt_username.Text == String.IsNullOrEmpty || txt_password.Text == String.IsNullOrEmpty || txt_repeat.Text == String.IsNullOrEmpty || txt_mail.Text == String.IsNullOrEmpty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Plesae insert your username and password");
    }
    else
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = " select * from Login where UserName =' " + txtbox_user.Text + " ' and PassWord = ' " + txtbox_password.Text + " ' ";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome!");
            LearnerForm F2 = new LearnerForm();
            F2.Show();
        }
        if (count > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username or Password");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is not correct");
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: well we can be sure that count is = 1 or less..,, check your else statment and output sql ecc to understand what you are doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one extra space after quote `'`. Remove it:

```
where UserName =' " + txtbox_user.Text + " ' and PassWord = ' " + txtbox_password.Text + " '
```

should be:

```
where UserName ='" + txtbox_user.Text + "' and PassWord = '" + txtbox_password.Text + "'
```

Also I strongly recommend that you always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks @user2946329. It worked, Now , I can login  But it still shows the "Username or Password is not correct".

Comment: @user3585203 ... You should also change your `if` statement to `else if` properly. Chane second `if` to `else if`...

Comment: @user3585203 : your second `if` should be a `else if`.